# Too much elements of vector . Combinations program

Tags: c++, memory, vector, time, statistics

Well Hi guys

I am making a project for lotto statistics and basically it has class "kombinacije4" which has attributes as first num second num third num fourth num and date and time when it last appeared and how much times did the combination show up.

```
class kombinacije4 {
public:
    Date date;
    Time time;
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
    int fourth;

    int howMuchRoundsDidntShowedUp;
    int howMuchTimesAppeared;
    void GetCombination(int, int, int, int);
    void GetCombinationsAfterRound(int);
};
```

Then I have vector of these elements

```
std::vector<kombinacije4> fourties;
```

I initialize this vector pretty fast and well but I have a problem when I want to change these attributes like when it last showed up date and time or how much it showed up, because there is 80 numbers and in one round they draw 20 numbers. From these 20 numbers I have to make combinations of 4 and find them in `fourties` and change their attributes. FOR seven hundred times.Because there is 700 rounds. Does anyone have an idea how can I directly access by their values. Maybe `std::find`can do something? Obviously I have time limit problem.

Any Idea of doing this program on the other way?

```
for(auto i=round.begin();i!=round.end();i++){
        for(auto j=i+1;j!=round.end();j++){
            for(auto k=j+1;k!=round.end();k++){
                for(auto l=k+1;l!=round.end();l++){
                    for(auto p=fourties.begin();p!=fourties.end();p++){
                        -if-statement
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  Obviously this block is going to pass 3 million times through the vector of million and half elements
```

THANKS !

Comment: A few remarks: 1) What does `if-statement` do? If it does not change the size of round, then instead of having 4 nested loops `i, j, k, l`, you could pre-compute number of times `if-statement` will execute (it will depend on round.size()) and have only one loop. 2) Vrijeme is not an English word. Don't mix two languages when posting questions to stack overflow.

Comment: if-statement means if in round there is combination that is drawn, it's going to search for that combination through whole vector of 1 580 512 combinations and IF IT IS FOUND(if statement) change  `howMuchRoundsDidntShowedUp` and `howMuchTimesAppeared` eventually date and time. I just forgot to change that word but it's just single word. Best regards

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that `for_each_combination` from this library would be helpful: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/combinations

Answer (score 0):

To access the members of an object inside a vector you should just use `myobject[iterator].membername`.

For example:

```
for (auto p = fourties.begin(); p!= fourties.end(); p++)
{
    if (fourties.at[p].first == "your data" && 
        fourties.at[p].second == "your data" && 
        fourties.at[p].third == "your data"  && 
        fourties.at[p].fourth == "your data")
    {
        fourties.at[p].date = 'your data';
        fourties.at[p].time = 'your data';
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand. I need something quicker for passing through the vector. Maybe another container type of data or something else?

Comment: You could add an if statement in each of the `round` for loops in your program, check for the presence of that number in `fourties` and only proceed if the check is positive. You would trade four checks for several loops in the inner structure in about 80% of circumstances